# Splitting a wide table or a longtable into two blocks

Tags: longtable

I have a very wide table (code below). I would like to put a small gap between the data under "First Group" and "Second Group" - two of the main multicolumns column headers. I tried putting in a double pipe (||) between these two columns where I specify the longtable. It splits the table but it behaves very weirdly in the multicolumn rows. How can I make the table split cleanly from top to bottom, hopefully without having to wade through the miles of code looking for &s? Thanks for your time!

Code for my table follows:

```
\documentclass[6pt]{article}
\usepackage[portrait, total={5.45in, 8.5in}, top=1.25in, bottom=1.25in, right=1.25in, left=1.5in, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default]{cantarell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\definecolor{tableShade2}{HTML}{F1F5FA}
\definecolor{tableShade}{HTML}{FAFAFD}
\definecolor{tableShade3}{HTML}{dddddd}
\definecolor{tableShade4}{HTML}{C2A5CF}
\definecolor{tableShade5}{HTML}{E7D4E8}
\definecolor{tableShade6}{HTML}{A1D99B}
\definecolor{tableShade7}{HTML}{D9F0D3}
\definecolor{tableShade1}{HTML}{FFEDA0}

\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\raggedright}p{#1}}
\arrayrulecolor{tableShade3}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\scriptsize{\textbf{A very wide table with two groups}}\end{center}
\setlength\LTleft{0in}
\setlength\LTright{1.25in}
\setlength\LTpre{-0.3cm}
\setlength\LTpost{0in}
\rowcolors{1}{tableShade2}{white}\scriptsize
\newcommand{\CTPanel}[1]{%
\multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{white}}r|}{#1}}
\centering
\begin{longtable}{lp{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}||p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}}

\hiderowcolors
&\multicolumn{9}{c}{First Group}&\multicolumn{9}{c}{Second Group}\\\cmidrule(lr){2-10}\cmidrule(lr){11-19}
something&\multicolumn{2}{c}{AB} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ABCD} & \multicolumn{4}{c||}{ABCD EFGH}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{AB} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ABCD} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{ABCD EFGH}\\\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-10}\cmidrule(lr){11-12}\cmidrule(lr){13-15}\cmidrule(lr){16-19}
Characteristics & + & - & I & II & III & $L^{A}$ & $L^{B}$ & $H^{+}$ & TN & + & - & I & II & III & $L^{A}$ & $L^{B}$ & $H^{+}$ & TN\\
\specialrule{0.02em}{0.1em}{0em}
\endhead
\specialrule{0.02em}{0em}{0em}
\endfoot
\hline
\multicolumn{10}{l}{\textbf{The first subheading}}\\\hline
\showrowcolors
some variable &+&+&-&+&+&-&-&-&-&-&+&+&-&-&+&+&-&-\\\hline
some other variable &+&+&-&+&+&-&-&-&-&-&+&+&-&-&+&+&-&-\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Resulting table (after edits suggested by D. Carlisle):
[image: Table with pipes and multicolumns as suggested in answer 1.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on David Carlisle's answer and comments, this hack gives a better impression of the longtable being split into two distinct blocks. It uses a wide vertical white rule to split the parts of the table. Hence it looks better if the all the table rows (or just alternate rows) are coloured with a different colour other than white.

```
\begin{longtable}{lp{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}!{\color{white}\vrule width 5pt}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}p{0.3cm}}
```

lead to:
[image: Table with wide 5pt white vertical rule emulating a break in the longtable]

One more interesting fact I learnt through this question is that it is possible to make vertical rules play well with multicolumns as well as the tricky booktabs package by using the `vrule` option.

For example, this code

```
\begin{longtable}{lp{0.3cm}!{\color{tableShade3}\vrule}
               p{0.3cm}!{\color{tableShade3}\vrule}
               p{0.3cm}!{\color{tableShade3}\vrule}
               p{0.3cm}!{\color{tableShade3}\vrule}
               p{0.3cm}!{\color{tableShade3}\vrule}
               p{0.3cm}!{\color{tableShade3}\vrule}
               p{0.3cm}!{\color{tableShade3}\vrule}
               p{0.3cm}!{\color{tableShade3}\vrule}
               p{0.3cm}!{\color{white}\vrule width 4pt}
               p{0.3cm}!{\color{white}\vrule}
               p{0.3cm}!{\color{white}\vrule}
               p{0.3cm}!{\color{white}\vrule}
               p{0.3cm}!{\color{white}\vrule}
               p{0.3cm}!{\color{white}\vrule}
               p{0.3cm}!{\color{white}\vrule}
               p{0.3cm}!{\color{white}\vrule}
               p{0.3cm}!{\color{white}\vrule}
               p{0.3cm}!{\color{white}\vrule}}
```

leads to:

[image: Table with vertical rules and booktabs playing well]

Not perfect, but functional and somewhat less ugly than the the | or || solution.

Answer (score 6):

whenever you use a `\multicolumn` that ends in a column that has any `|` or `@{...}` material in its right hand edge, you need to re-insert it so if you have

```
|ll||ll|
```

then typically you will need

```
\multicolumn{2}{|c||}{heading for 1st 2 columns}&
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{heading for 2nd 2 columns}\\
```

This applies to all LaTeX tabular environments.

Comment: Thanks very much for the fast response. I will keep this helpful tip in mind for future tables. Unfortunately, it doesn't help this table completely. I shortened the number of columns for the only multicolumn subheading that crossed the || and have modified the multicolumns with ABCD EFGH and AB as suggested. Now the split doesn't make it in 2 of the rows with regular columns (the one with the H+ TN .. and the last row with "some other variable"). Is there another solution to splitting rather than fighting with pipes?

Comment: Your vertical lines are there, but shifted up by strange amounts, whatever `\cmidrule(lr){2-10}\cmidrule(lr){11-19}` does it really doesn't like vertical rules. If I comment out each line that has those, the vertical lines shift back in to position. You could just use standard LaTeX `\cline` instead, possibly?

Comment: I used `\cmidrule` from the booktabs package. The main advantage of using `\cmidrule` is that the rule does not touch the "walls" of the cell. Using `\cline` makes it appear as a continuous rule undistinguished from `\hline`. `\cmidrule` comes with a small space before and after the rule separating it from the text in the cells. I wonder if this space is interfering with the vertical rules.

Comment: Yes I know but the booktabs documentation famously warns you that vertical rules are considered evil, so its horizontal rule commands not working with vertical rules may perhaps not be considered a bug. perhaps give up with the || and just have @{\hspace{....}} extra gap instead

Comment: I ended up doing a hacky 5pt wide white vertical rule to achieve the separate blocks effect. (Attached a screenshot above). Not perfect, but better than the || solution. Thanks again for your help.