# \midrule splits vertical lines in table

Tags: tables, rules, booktabs

I realise that the `booktabs` package does not want me to use vertical lines in my tables. However, I like vertical lines in my tables. Therefore, I am hoping there is a workaround to a problem that `booktabs` clearly does not think should even be an issue.

Here is my table:

[image: Table with borken up vertical lines]

Is it possible to join all the vertical lines?

Here is the code:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{centering}
\scalebox{.8}
\small
{\begin{tabular}{| c | l | c c c |}
\hline
{\bf HD Level}  &           &   &   &   \\
\midrule[2pt]
\multirow{2}*{1} & {\it Rep-tile}:  & $\{1,2\}$ & $\{1,3\}$ & $\{2,3\}$ \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
        & {\it Encoding}:\ \ \ \    & 1     & 2         & 3 \\
\midrule[2pt]
\multirow{2}*{2} & {\it Rep-tile}:  & $\{2\}$   & $\{3\}$   & \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
        & {\it Encoding}:   & 1     & 2     & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{\small\bf Bla bla}
\label{tab:SMuTexEncoding}
\end{centering}
\end{table}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: don't use vertical lines when loading `booktabs`!

Comment: That's the nature of the beast... when using [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs), you need to consider reading the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) as well. It states: "You will not go far wrong if you remember two simple guidelines at all times: 1. Never, ever use vertical rules. 2. Never use double rules."

Comment: I did @Werner (and implied as much at the beginning of my question)! But what if I happen to disagree? Perhaps there is another package you can suggest? I need the \cmidrule{2-5} function...

Comment: Not a purist answer, but I usually try and trick vertical lines into a table using [a workaround such as this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45976/splitting-a-wide-table-or-a-longtable-into-two-blocks/51670#51670).

Comment: You may disagree, of course, but then you can't use `booktabs`. I invite you to look at my realization of your table in [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg6nz.png). I would probably remove the `\cmidrule{2-5}` commands too. The superheavy rules are out of the question.

Comment: Thanks @Ariel, but it looks a bit like overkill. I need something pretty simple.

Comment: @egreg, your solution is what booktabs would like me to do; Thanks anyway...

Comment: If you *must* use vertical rules and still want better spacing around the horizontal rules, you could proceed by inserting (typographic) struts. See, e.g., http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165659/5001. However, in that case don't use `booktabs`.

Comment: You don't have to use `booktabs`. Basic LaTeX provides `cline`. Please note, that `\it` is deprecated for about 20 years now.

Comment: @pdini Well, the reasons why `booktabs` avoids the use of vertical lines in a table, is because they are redundant most of the time. Especially if it comes to the outer edges of the table. From the point of view of visual design they are not necessary because the vertical margins of the book or the page containing this table serve as such and are therefore unnecessary.

Comment: @pdini Of course we're talking about tables and well-composed pages, something not so difficult to achieve with `LaTeX`. Internally, depending on the type of information contained in the table may require an internal vertical line or some other typographical distinction as the case may.

But anyway if good design doesn't mind, and you want yes or yes use vertical lines, my suggestion is to **don't use** `booktabs` and instead you can manually setting the stroke width of the lines, just as egreg or Johannes_B suggested.

Comment: Just use a standard `\cline` if you are using vertical rules. Also `\scalebox{.8}\small` makes a box with just the argument `\small` which is odd??

Comment: Thanks very much everyone, this is really helpful. Indeed, the fact I still use \it shows my age!! :) I'll try to catch up, promise!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have thick  `\hline`s with the `makecell` package and its `\Xhline{width}` and `\Xcline{col1-col2}{width}` commands. You can replace the vertical spacing added by `booktabs` around horizontal rules (that's responsible for non joining vertical rules) with the `cellspace` package; it lets you define minimal vertical spacingabove and below cells of a given column, prefixing its specifier with the letter `S`.

I also took the opportunity to define a `set` command, based on an example in the documentation of the `mathtools` package, that produces better horizontal spacing and variable-sized  braces

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\set[1]\{\}{\nonscript\,#1\nonscript\,}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{| Sc | >{\itshape}l | Sc c c |}
\hline
{\bfseries HD Level} & & & & \\
\Xhline{2pt}
\multirow{2}{*}{1} & Rep-tile: & $\set{1,2}$ & $\set{1,3}$ & $\set{2,3}$ \\
\cline{2-5}
        & Encoding:\ \ \ \ & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\Xhline{2pt}
\multirow{2}{*}{2} & Rep-tile: & $\set{2}$ & $\set{3}$ & \\
\cline{2-5}
        & Encoding: & 1 & 2 & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\small\bf Bla bla}
\label{tab:SMuTexEncoding}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to have coloured rules, it's more complelex: the `\arrayrulecolor` command (from the `colortbl` package) doesn't work. A workaround consistsin using the `hhline` package, setting `\arrayrulewidth` to 0pt and colouring the interrule space of a double rule. Demo:

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\small\arrayrulecolor{red}
\begin{tabular}{| Sc | >{\itshape}l | Sc c c |}
\hline
{\bfseries HD Level} & & & & \\
\Xhline{2pt}
\multirow{2}{*}{1} & Rep-tile: & $\set{1,2}$ & $\set{1,3}$ & $\set{2,3}$ \\
\cline{2-5}
        & Encoding:\ \ \ \ & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\Xhline{2pt}
\multirow{2}{*}{2} & Rep-tile: & $\set{2}$ & $\set{3}$ & \\
\cline{2-5}
        & Encoding: & 1 & 2 & \\
\hhline{>{\arrayrulewidth = 0pt\doublerulesep = 2pt \doublerulesepcolor{red}}=====}
\end{tabular}
\caption{\small\bf Bla bla}
\label{tab:SMuTexEncoding}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, that's what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @pdini: Just in case, note it doesn't work for coloured rules. A workaround consists in using `hhline`. You can take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Needed to say, I would reject both these tables as a copy editor. But I know, it's not the question here. :(

Comment: @tohecz. I agree with. The second one is only to illustrate the problem of `\Xh/cline` with colour. However, I've *some* special cases where a table required vertical and horizontal lines — I mean they were meaningful.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard, that looks very nice too. Good to know I can create coloured tables.

Answer (score 6):

I would ***never*** do what I did in the first table, but it is your choice, not mine. I just offer a much nicer alternative. However, please:

- Do not use `\it` and `\bf`: [Does it matter if I use \textit or \it, \bfseries or \bf, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc)
- Do not manually modify the size of the table nor the style of the caption, it's not semantic. What if you later decide that the captions should not be bold, but you've already add `\bfseries` to 50 captions? Are you going to remove them by hand? Well, you'll have to. Or you use packages that modify the styles globally. (Both things can be found on this website, however, simply look into the documentation of packages `caption` and `float`.)
- Do not specify `[h]` float placement alone, you can expect bad things happening.
- `centering` is not an environment, it is a command: `\centering`.
- Your `\scalebox` has no effect whatsoever since the thing you scale is the macro `\small`, which doesn't output anything. Use either `\scalebox` or `\small` (or rather none of them).

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{4.5ex}}c}

\makeatletter
\def\Hline{% a thicker \hline
  \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\hrule \@height 1pt \futurelet
   \reserved@a\@xhline}
\makeatother

\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand\Midrule{\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| c | l @{\qquad} | c c C |}
\Hline
  \bfseries HD Level  &&&&\\
\hline
  1 & \itshape Rep-tile:  & $\{1,2\}$ & $\{1,3\}$ & $\{2,3\}$ \\
\cline{2-5}
    & \itshape Encoding: & 1       & 2       & 3 \\
\Hline
  2 & \itshape Rep-tile: & $\{2\}$ & $\{3\}$ & \\
\cline{2-5}
    & \itshape Encoding: & 1       & 2       & \\
\Hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Bla bla}
\label{tab:SMuTexEncoding}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ c >{\itshape}l c c c }\toprule
\bfseries HD Level\\\Midrule
1 & Rep-tile: & $\{1,2\}$ & $\{1,3\}$ & $\{2,3\}$ \\\cmidrule{2-5}
  & Encoding: & 1         & 2         & 3 \\\Midrule
2 & Rep-tile: & $\{2\}$   & $\{3\}$   & \\\cmidrule{2-5}
  & Encoding: & 1         & 2         & \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Bla bla}
\label{tab:SMuTexEncoding}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @tohecz. I guess you can probably date me from my coding 'style': i started using TeX in 1986, and never quite got used to LaTeX! I will keep in mind the other points you made, although I don't quite understand them (what's so bad about \bf? etc). I was able to do a table without vertical lines too, and using the multirow function, and I have to admit I am getting used to the look. It's nicer than the one you kindly put together for me and have very clearly disowned :)

Comment: @pdini see [Does it matter if I use \textit or \it, \bfseries or \bf, etc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc)

Comment: I see! Interesting. I had in fact wondered why it was not possible to get bold italicised text. I'll start using the proper commands then. Thanks @tohecz

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want vertical rules compatible with the rules of `booktabs`, you should use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\small
\begin{NiceTabular}{| c | >{\itshape}l | c c c |}
\hline
\bfseries HD Level  & &   &   &   \\
\midrule[2pt]
\Block{2-1}{1} & Rep-tile  & $\{1,2\}$ & $\{1,3\}$ & $\{2,3\}$ \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
               & Encoding  & 1         & 2         & 3 \\
\midrule[2pt]
\Block{2-1}{2} & Rep-tile  & $\{2\}$   & $\{3\}$   & \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
               & Encoding  & 1         & 2         & \\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{\small\bfseries Bla bla}
\label{tab:SMuTexEncoding}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you, @F. Pantigny, I'll keep that in mind.